# Django - how to write such widget / field for django fields?

Tags: django, forms, list, widget, field

Hí, I would like to make new field, which render like this:

[image]

```
<table>
    <tr><td colspan="3">
    <select id="item_id" size="6" style="width: 100%;">
      <option>Apple</option>
      <option>Pear</option>
      <option>Banana</option>
      <option>Orange</option>
    </select>
    </td></tr>
    <tr><td>
        <input type="text" id="item_id_add" />
    </td><td>
        <button type="button" onclick="addElement('item_id')">Add</button>
    </td><td>
        <button type="button" onclick="removeElement('item_id')">Remove</button>
    </td></tr>
</table>
```

Where user can add and remove options, and all of these options will be submitted (i want to allow user to define his own lists). I know how to do it in HTML / JS, but i dont know how to make django render a field to look like i want.

How to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there are 3 main steps for this :

1-> create a [model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/) which includes these fields and a owner/user field ( to connect to Django-User Model)

2->create a [form](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/) (i prefer a [ModelForm](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/) [to let the form editable])

3-> create a [view](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/views/) related to your form.

4-> ( i know i said 3 steps :)) create a template file which is told in your view to render that form in basic HTML file ( with [django template language](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/) )

to code that simple form ; actually you need to get django - basics. so you can start here:

[Django Project](http://www.djangoproject.com)